# What is the purpose of dot in front of column name

Tags: python

I was copying a code from Kaggle. Suddenly I saw this line of code used on the dataset. I always used `.` when I have to access the specific function of the library, but I don't why it is use in front of column name.

`Age` is column name in the dataset

```
 train.loc[train.Age.isnull(), 'Age'] = train.groupby("Pclass").Age.transform('median')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that code is using the Pandas library.

In Pandas you can access a column in two ways: df["column"] or df.column.

The first way is usually recommended: "The attribute will not be available if it conflicts with an existing method name, e.g. s.min is not allowed, but s['min'] is possible."

Answer (score 0):

At python, dot means that you are looking for an attribute of a specific object. For example, we have an object `train.groupby("Pclass")` and this object has an attribute `Age`. To access this attribute we are doing this `object.attribute` --> `train.groupby("Pclass").Age`. In your case this is mean, that Age-column under the hood is an attribute.